# iOS animationImages:   I like to move it while it plays

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have successfully created a UIView which plays an animation of images from an NSArray of images. I am trying to get this image to move at the same time the animation is playing. Use of the .center property of UIView just isn't working, and I must have some sort of syntactic error, which I cannot for the life of me figure out.

Original post:

I'm playing with brandontreb's tutorial. I can successfully get the animated sprite to dance in place, but I want it to actually scoot across the screen.  Can some dear soul:

1. Please help me fix what I'm doing wrong to make the center of the UIimage
   actually move across screen?
2. Or even better, update this to 
   "animation block" best practices?

I will surely study your fixes for hours.

```
- (IBAction)startWalking:(UIButton *)sender {
NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                         nil];
UIImageView * ryuJump = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(100, 125, 150, 130)];
ryuJump.animationImages = imageArray;
ryuJump.animationDuration = 1.1;
ryuJump.animationRepeatCount=5;
CGPoint p = ryuJump.center;
p.x += 100;
ryuJump.center = p;

[UIView animateWithDuration:20
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     ryuJump.center = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
ryuJump.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
[self.view addSubview:ryuJump];
[ryuJump startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't literally want to change a cyclic "fight cycle" cartoon sprite animation and turn into a "walk cycle" animation. I just want to translate an animation across screen.

Comment: Understanding why it's a bad question would help. I have been unable after reading over 20 googled tutorials on the topic been able to get the two concepts together-- animatED image and translated image. No one can say there isn't research, effort, and a clear request being made here.

Comment: The first version of your question read basically "give me code". Your updated question is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove:

```
ryuJump.center = p;
```

You're basically telling uiview to animate to the exact same position you just set it to (so nothing will happen).

Comment: Whoo-hoo! That fixed it! Thanks, mon!  I know see another problem is that I may have underestimated what 100 pixels of motion would have actually looked like.